# How to check for specific keydown with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

1. My first question is why do I have to take away parentheses
   when I call the function : `redManMovement`?
   If I call it `redManMovement()` it moves without any key down
2. How do I check if specific buttons are down?
   This seems like something that I can't do because I can't call a parameter to
   the `redManMovement`, so I cannot use the `which()` function.

p.s. I just started Javascript yesterday.

```
function redManMovement(){
    redManY -= 10 ;
}
function moveEverything(){                   // Calculate Movements 
    window.addEventListener("keydown",redManMovement,false);
}
```

Comment: "*Why do i have to take away parentheses when i call the function*" - because you are *not* calling it. It will get called when the event happens.

Comment: What `which` function do you refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you use `redManMovement()` at `.addEventListener()` the function will be executed immediately
2. The `event` argument is omitted from the `redManMovement` function, which would allow you to get `event.which`; e.g.,

```
// where `redManY` is defined, i.e., `var redManY = 0`

function redManMovement(event) {
  console.log(event.which); // or `event.keyCode`
  redManY -= 10 ;
}
```